# Collapsing error on IE Mobile with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, windows-mobile

As you know we can use this kind of syntax, introduced by bootstrap, to collapse a div when clicking on a button.

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myid">
  <ul id="myid" class='collapse'>
```

But, actually it doesn't work (it stays open) with the Bootstrap version 3.2.0 and Windows Mobile (IE11 Emulate it correctly)

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to add this 2 lines of code:

```
.collapse.in {
    display: block;
}

.collapse {
    display: none;
}
```